# error while compiling Yacc and lex files

Tags: yacc, lex

I've tried to do something with Lex and Yacc, but I had this error:

```
calc.l:4:8: error expected ‘=’ ‘ ’ ‘ ’ ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before numeric constant
calc.y: In function 'yyparse':
calc.y:11:6: error: expected expression before '[' token
```

calc.y:11:12: error: expected expression before '}' token

I used this lines to generate the files:

```
yacc -d calc.y
flex calc.l
```

and then i used gcc for both generated C files.

sorry right now I'm not on my computer i only have the error lines saved, so i only want to know whether this errors are because I forgot something ?

P.S: sorry i couldn't come with the code, but I'll try to edit thi later.

Comment: You most likely have an error in `calc.y` or `calc.l`. Show us those files.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves problem solved, I declared something in calc.l and declared it and calc.y as token; after I removed it from the lex files it works fine. though my code was kinda copy past from my instructors example.